# Display db data in edit page

Tags: codeigniter

I am working with a **registered_member_data_edit** page?

My controller function is

```
function edit_profile()
    {
        $data['title']= 'Edit Profile';
        $member_id = $this->session->userdata('member_id');
        $this->load->model('user_model','',TRUE);
        $data['row'] = $this->user_model->edit_user($member_id)->result();
        $this->load->view('edit_profile.php', $this->data);
    }
```

My model function is

```
public function edit_user($member_id)
    {
            $this->db->select('fullname','country','district','address','nominee_name','nominee_relation','mobile_no','password','bank_acc_no','bank_acc_name','bank_name','branch_name');
            return $this->db->get_where('user', array('member_id'=> $member_id));
    }
```

My view page is like

```
<p><label>User Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-short" value="" /></p>
```

What should I put in the value to show the db data in edit page?

Comment: How many rows are returned from the database?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function edit_user($member_id)
    {
            $this->db->select('fullname','country','district','address','nominee_name','nominee_relation','mobile_no','password','bank_acc_no','bank_acc_name','bank_name','branch_name');
            return $this->db->get_where('user', array('member_id'=> $member_id));
    }
```

this will return the object, which you have in `$data['row']` and that variable you are sending to view file.

So in view file, you can access the all data of the object using `$row`.

So from here you have 2 options

1. Even that function returning only 1 row, you have to access using `foreach($row->result() as $_data)` and after that you can access each and every column as `$_data->fullname` like that.
2. You can convert that object to array using `$row = $row->result_array()` and you can access the database column using `$row[0]['fullname']` like that.

Best luck.

Comment: Can I write the view file like
<p><label>User Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-short" value="<?php $row[0]['fullname'];?>" /></p>